# Disable “Exclusive Access to Memory” runtime check doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Xcode:** 10.2.1 (10E1001)

**Swift:** 5.0.1

I'm trying to disable the “Exclusive Access to Memory” runtime check to avoid crashes until I can figure out a nice solution for the actual "Simultaneous access" problems. However the app will crash every time even though the check is already disabled as specified in official documentation:

[image]

According to https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-exclusivity/#impact-on-swift-projects the following should be enough:

**xcodeproj/project.pbxproj**

[image]

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-enforce-exclusivity=none";
SWIFT_ENFORCE_EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS = none;
```

Also tried:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-enforce-exclusivity=unchecked";
SWIFT_ENFORCE_EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS = none;
```

-

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-enforce-exclusivity=none -enforce-exclusivity=unchecked";
SWIFT_ENFORCE_EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS = none;
```

Am I missing something that doesn't let me disable this enforced exclusive access?

Comment: Check the build settings for your target (rather than project) – is "Exclusive Access to Memory" also set to "none" there?

Comment: It is set in there as well

Comment: Can you post a (minimal) example which demonstrates the problem?